# Hiero not opening in IntelliJ with libGDX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm trying to run Hiero in my java libGDX project but it won't open.

I tried to run Hiero with the desktop modules (desktop and desktop.main). I also tried changing the dependency in `build.gradle`. It wouldn't run with desktop but with desktop.main it ran and the Hiero loading screen popped up but then lots of error messages were shown.

Here are the errors produced when running with desktop:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.badlogic.gdx.tools.hiero.Hiero
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.tools.hiero.Hiero

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code in `DesktopLauncher.java`:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;
import com.mygdx.game.Happy_Warfare;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
        config.setForegroundFPS(60);

        config.setTitle("Happy Warfare");
        new Lwjgl3Application(new Happy_Warfare(), config);
    }
```

Here is the code in build.gradle:

> buildscript {
>
> ```
> repositories {
>     mavenLocal()
>     mavenCentral()
>     gradlePluginPortal()
>     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
>     google()
> }
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.1.16'
>     classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.0.7'
>     
>
> } }
> ```
>
> allprojects {
> apply plugin: "eclipse"
>
> ```
> version = '1.0'
> ext {
>     appName = "Happy Warfare"
>     gdxVersion = '1.12.0'
>     roboVMVersion = '2.3.19'
>     box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
>     ashleyVersion = '1.7.4'
>     aiVersion = '1.8.2'
>     gdxControllersVersion = '2.2.1'
> }
>
> repositories {
>     mavenLocal()
>     mavenCentral()
>     google()
>     gradlePluginPortal()
>     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
>     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
>     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
> } }
> ```
>
> project(":desktop") {
> apply plugin: "java-library"
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     implementation project(":core")
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
>     
> } }
> ```
>
> project(":html") {
> apply plugin: "java-library"
> apply plugin: "gwt"
> apply plugin: "war"
> apply plugin: "org.gretty"
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     implementation project(":core")
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
>     
> } }
> ```
>
> project(":core") {
> apply plugin: "java-library"
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
>     api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
>     // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx-tools
>     //        implementation group: 'com.badlogicgames.gdx', name: 'gdx-tools', version: '1.12.1'
> } }
> ```

```
Any help would be appreciated.
```

Comment: Can u post your main build.gradle file, it probably not running due to missing declaration of "com.gdx.tools. " in ur project level build.gradle

Comment: @Naruto26 I think I've added it there now

Comment: the desktop dependencies block seem to be missing the tools dependency

Comment: @Naruto26 I read a section on the wiki and it says:                                                 Tools
Core Dependency: Don’t put me in core!

Desktop Dependency (LWJGL2 only):

api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"                                                My project uses LWJGL3 so maybe it just isn't able to work at all?

Comment: just put this in your desktop dependency block         
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"